# Color shading inside PieChart IOS

Tags: ios, swift4

I need to create a color shading effect inside the pie chart for a particular slice only.The required image is as shown( need a light orange color inside the piechart corresponding to orange slice)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkM9a.png]

Iam using cocoapods charts library. This is the function:

```
 let approvedColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 19/255, green: 195/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1.0)
 let pendingColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 148/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
 let rejectedColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 225/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1.0)
 let surveyData = [50,40,10]

func fillChart() {
    var dataEntries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
    for (val) in surveyData {
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(val), label: nil)
        dataEntries.append(entry)

    }
    let chartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    chartDataSet.colors = [approvedColor,pendingColor,rejectedColor]
    chartDataSet.sliceSpace = 0
    chartDataSet.selectionShift = 5

    let chartData = PieChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

    chartView.data = chartData
}
```

Comment: Which library you are using? And please share some code of your pie chart if you made it yourself.

Comment: Iam using cocoapods charts library.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular library, but you should be setting the alpha of the color for the fill to something like 50% or less.

Comment: I want to set it for one slice only. How to do that?

Comment: @angel9226 You will have to add another `CAShapeLayer` for that part only.